# Instruments and leaks

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios, memory-leaks, instruments

I am testing my app and I keep getting these leaks but none of them are in my code..I think, has anyone else had these issues?

```
__NSCFDictionary        0x5f8cfe0   48  AudioToolbox    SimAggregateDevice::SimAggregateDevice(__CFString const*, __CFString const*, long&)

Malloc 32 Bytes     0x5f83a00   32  AudioToolbox    SimAggregateDevice::SimAggregateDevice(__CFString const*, __CFString const*, long&)

Malloc 48 Bytes     0x5f839d0   48  AudioToolbox    SimAggregateDevice::SimAggregateDevice(__CFString const*, __CFString const*, long&)

Malloc 32 Bytes     0x5f839b0   32  AudioToolbox    CreateDictionaryForDevice(unsigned long)

Malloc 32 Bytes     0x5f83990   32  AudioToolbox    CreateDictionaryForDevice(unsigned long)
__NSCFDictionary        0x5f83960   48  AudioToolbox    CreateDictionaryForDevice(unsigned long)

Malloc 32 Bytes     0x5f83940   32  AudioToolbox    SimAggregateDevice::SimAggregateDevice(__CFString const*, __CFString const*, long&)

__NSCFArray     0x5f838b0   32  AudioToolbox    SimAggregateDevice::SimAggregateDevice(__CFString const*, __CFString const*, long&)
```

any help would be awesome and thank you from... yes... a newbie.

Comment: Can you post more info?  It's probably those NSStrings or CFDictionary's that are not getting released properly.  You can see a complete trace of when memory is alloc, init, retained, released, and dealloc'd when you drill into a specific HEX address

Comment: A little more info would be very helpful here. Like what your code is trying to do, code snippets, anything. You haven't given us much to work with.

Comment: WWDC10 videos include multiple sessions on Instruments and other Developer Tools http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

Comment: @slf I am using MPMovieplayerViewController in a UIScrollview and when I run one of the videos I get this leak. Maybe I am not releasing it properly or not at all? -(IBAction)shimmyVideo:(id)sender
{
 NSString *url = @"http://www.andalee.com/iPhoneVideos/MeDrumming.MP4";
 MPMoviePlayerViewController* moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
 [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
 
} @brenton Do I need to release the string "url"?

Comment: could you post some snippets here or use http://pastie.org/ or https://gist.github.com/ the comments section is very difficult to debug

Comment: I ran it on the device and it ran fine with no leaks, so I guess it was just because I was in the simulator... I hope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, I think you're running your app on the simulator - you shouldn't.

Or rather, never use the simulator to test for memory allocations, leaks, etc. You should always run it on the device itself.

I think if you run it on the device you'll still see this leak (well, you'll see something similar), if you google the various things you're getting back you'll see other people having this problem. It appears as if there are some small leaks within the framework itself, which is something outside of your control. I'd just leave them be.

Comment: Yeah I am testing for the most part in the simulator, but I have ran it on the device and it seem that I am getting the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Also try the static analysis build.  That will often reveal retain/release mismatches and general leaks.  You can run it with Cmd+Shift+A (I think).

Comment: when I run the analysis build it runs fine and I get no leaks or errors.